# Oracle Query with 'WITH' clause - What is the equivalent for SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, oracle11g

I have a query in Oracle which contains 'WITH' clause and working fine. But, what is the equivalent in SQLite without using 'WITH' clause?
I have an old SQLite version which does not support WITH clause and due to some constraints, we should not upgrade it.

I have option of using 'UNION' in SQLite, but I want to know is there any other way without using it UNION to achieve the same result as using WITH.
Reason not using UNION is, with WITH clause, it returns recursively without limitation which is not the case with limited UNION clauses.

Following is the query in Oracle:

```
WITH tree (affiliation_id,
from_customer_id,
to_customer_id,
to_name,name, parent_customer_type, child_customer_type, level1)
AS
(
SELECT af.affiliation_id,
from_customer_id ,
to_customer_id,
to_name,
c.name as name,
parent_customer_type, child_customer_type,0 AS LEVEL1
FROM customer_affiliation af, customer c
WHERE to_customer_id != from_customer_id
and af.from_customer_id = c.customer_id
and to_customer_id = 1000022559337
UNION ALL
SELECT af.affiliation_id,
af.from_customer_id,
af.to_customer_id,
af.to_name,c.name, af.parent_customer_type, af.child_customer_type,Level1 + 1 AS LEVEL1    FROM customer c,  affiliation af
INNER JOIN tree smr ON smr.from_customer_id = af.to_customer_id
where  af.from_customer_id = c.customer_id
)
SELECT affiliation_id,
to_customer_id parent,
from_customer_id child,
to_name,name, parent_customer_type, child_customer_type,LEVEL1 FROM tree;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without WITH, it is not possible to do recursive queries in SQLite.

You would have to do every iteration manually from your application code.

You should upgrade SQLite.